# vim visual block doesen't erase the full selection

Tags: vim

I'm triyng to use Vim to edit several files, with the following format:

```
   "10000 700 file1.dat 2.154" | /Documents/etc
   "10000 700 file2.dat 2.154" | /Documents/etc
```

Each file contains several lines of code all with the exact same format, but the bit that goes `2.154` just before the double quotes needs to be changed every file, so I thought that using visual block would help change it more easily.

I start by putting the cursor in the first number, the `2` in this case, going to visual block mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> and then moving to the last rank, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>, and the cursor keys to move to the `4`, just next to the closing double quotes, `"`, and use the <kbd>X</kbd> key to remove the old data, or the <kbd>S</kbd> key to substitute it with my new value, but if the selection gets to the `4`, when I type <kbd>S</kbd>, the column of `4`s remains in the file, and if I go one additional column to the right and select the double quotes, `"`, the behaviour of the editor changes, and it will select the quotes erasing them, forcing me to rewrite them.

The problem is more annoying that other thing, but still it would be nice to know why the visual block is refusing to select the last character or selecting the quotes as well.

I'm using Vim 7.4 with this `.vimrc`:

```
filetype indent plugin on
syntax on
set hlsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set autoindent
set nostartofline
set ruler
set number
set lbr
set showmatch
colorscheme  torte
```

Comment: I was unable to replicate the behaviour you are describing. I suggest you post a larger file excerpt and the exact key sequence, the unwanted result and the expected behaviour. You could consider using a [plugin](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) or the built-in search&replace.

Comment: If I may ask, what kind of plugins wold be adequate for this kind of trouble? I've already updated the info on the key sequence but still is not too long to replicate.

Comment: I can't replicate this behaviour, using vim `7.4.52` or `8.0.329`. I have a few suggestion, though. Use a square instead of the underline as the cursor often makes selection easier in vim. Try upgrading vim. Try on another system.

Comment: Could you use a global substitution to delete those parts of the line?

Comment: I've done it in a different terminal window, and it appears that the source of the problem it is the current terminal I'm using, the break lines in particular, if the selection is too close to a line break is when the odd behaviour happens, if i change the size of the terminal, the problem goes away, thanks a lot for the advice and the commendations